# Linear Algebra intuition behind subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I am trying to understand better the intuition behind subspaces. I am aware that the subspace of a vector space must have zero(go through the origin), has to be closed by addition, and has to be closed by multiplication. The aspect I fail to understand is why must it equal zero/go through the origin. If anyone has any analogy for subspaces I'd also love to hear it thank you.

Comment: “[a subspace] must equal zero” isn't quite the right notion.  It's better to say the subspace *contains* zero.

Answer (score 2):

A subspace has to be a vector space and therefore must be closed under scalar multiplication. There is always a $0$ value in the field of scalars, so $0\cdot\vec v$, which is the origin $\vec0$, has to be in the subspace.

You might be familiar with thinking of Euclidean vector spaces like $\mathbb R^3$, where the nontrivial subspaces are lines or planes through the origin. The collection of lines or planes that don’t necessarily go through the origin are called “[affine spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space)” or “affine subspaces,”* but those are not vector spaces if they don’t go through the origin.

*Like sometimes happens with mathematical definitions more than in English, the adjective “affine” is not restrictive; affine subspaces are not necessarily subspaces.

Comment: Another point: Since a subspace is closed under scalar multiplication, for any v in the subspace (-1)v= -v is also in the subspace.  Then, since a subspace is also closed under vector addition, v+ (-v)= 0 is in the subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Closed by multiplication $\implies$ zero must be in the subspace $U\subseteq V$, as stated at the answer above. Also, a *subspace* is, in particular, a *vector space* and vector spaces must have a neutral element: the vector $e\in U$ for which $u+e=u$ for all vectors $u\in U$. And by unicity of the neutral element of the "bigger" vector space $V$, the element $e\in U$ with that property must be the same element as the neutral of $V$, that is: *zero*.

Indeed, you only prove that zero is in $U$ ($U$ is the set you want to be a subspace) to conclude that $U\not = \emptyset$, because although $\emptyset$ is vacuosly closed by addition and multiplication, it doesn't have a neutral element (hence is not a vector space). So, on proving that $U$ is a subspace you can show that $0\in U$ or that $c \in U$ for some convenient constant vector (and show those "close properties")... Again, what really matters is that $U\not = \emptyset$.